# problem after dual boot with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I had already windows 7 in my laptop. I installed ubuntu16 using "Install ubuntu alongside windows 7" option. Ubuntu successfully installed but when I restart my laptop , the ubuntu boot menu appears and it shows option-

1. Boot from ubuntu
2. Boot from windows 7 OS.

If I select 1st option I can successfully enter in ubuntu.  But if I select 2nd option to boot in windows , Suddenly,a purple screen appears and laptop hangs. then I have to forcely restart my laptop.

What is the solution of this problem,How can I boot from windows?

Comment: Many guides on how to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu recommend manual partitioning instead of "Install ubuntu alongside windows 7". I guess that might be the problem. Please run this command and post the results, so that we can have a better understanding of your current partitions: `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. So is Windows hibernated or does it need chkdsk? If so you need to fix Windows using your Windows repair flash drive and its repair console.

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Boot-repair-disk

Boot into your ubuntu os and download the boot repair disk from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and extract it using [this](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html) to a usb-drive and reboot your laptop and boot up with the usb-drive.

After the boot-repair disk starts up go to the program and open the boot-repair program. Then follow the options and you will be able to fix your boot error.